# Develop a SSIS project in parallel

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, share

In a team of 2 developers, we have to implement a SSIS package with several Data Flow blocks. Ideally each developer would work on his set of components.

Is it possible to "share" the package and make it possible to work on the same solution without overwriting the colleague's changes?

A solution with copy/paste of the individual components from each developer into a unique, final solution would also be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not really, and you cant easily merge packages as you do with other types of files.

The solution to your case is to split the work you are doing in separate child packages and then use a parent package to coordinate the execution and call the children with the The Execute Package Task (which can also set any variable you may need on the child packages)

It sounds complicated at first but it is actually a good approach!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually your solution is elegant. I will further investigate it to see how it can fit our needs.

Answer (score 0):

Merging an SSIS package is difficult, there are some tools which make it easier. I would highly recommend taking a look at http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/ for a really helpful SSDT / BIDS helper plugin.

Another approach would be to have each developer build their data flows in separate packages then have a master package which controls execution flow and invokes the individual packages.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Diego's response: Have an overall design for the master package in place. As you progress, both the developers would most likely feel a need to modify the parent - discuss often and merge often to stay in sync both in design and its implementation.